# Property nil when using delegate to pass data back to VC

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates

I've got a view in a xib file that I load to my viewController - its a temp view and thus isn't on screen all the time. However the temp view and the main view, use the same view controller class as they both are doing the same job.

Now, in the xib view I load up a second viewControoler - lets call it viewControllerB - which is a UITableView with 197 cells. Once a cell is selected, the view is dismissed and the value of the cell is returned to viewControllerA.

viewControllerB is on the storyboard.

Here is the code I have used:

viewControllerB (The VC I need data back from)

Delegate Protocol:

```
@protocol CountrySelectedDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)selectedCountry: (id)countryReturned;

@end

@property (strong, nonatomic) id <CountrySelectedDelegate> myDelegate;
```

Then in the .m file:

Set the delegate:

```
ViewControllerA *viewA = [[ViewControllerA alloc]init];
    self.myDelegate = viewA;
```

Then I call the delegate in the same file;

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [[self myDelegate] selectedCountry:indexPath.row];


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Now in viewControllerA:

pragma mark - CountrySelected Delegate

```
-(void)selectedCountry:(id)countryReturned
{
    self.testInt = countryReturned;


}
```

Now this method does get called by the delegate. Looking in the console: countryReturned is the correct value. Once this method has finished, `self.testInt` is also the correct value.

Then, in my viewWillAppear method, I simply check the value again to see if its still the same with a NSLog print.

the value is always nil in the viewWillAppear method (Or anywhere else I check it) - I have tried with NSMutableString and NSString - always nil.

Why are my properties / instance variables getting set to nil?

**Update**:

This is how I show viewControllerB

```
- (IBAction)countrySelect:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UITableViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CountrySelection"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UINavigationControllerOperationPop;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: how u showing `viewcontrollerB`, as subView or presenting.?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to show that. Updating question now

Comment: First make your viewControllerB a strong property in viewControllerA so that it does not get deallocated once the countrySelect Method is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `ViewB` do the below I guess you have already done

```
@protocol CountrySelectedDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)selectedCountry: (NSInteger)countryReturned;

@end

@property (week, nonatomic) id <CountrySelectedDelegate> myDelegate;
```

and in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
if ([[self myDelegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedCountry:)]) 
{
    [[self myDelegate] selectedCountry:indexPath.row];
}
```

On `ViewA`

1. Conform the protocol

   ```
   @interface ViewA : UIViewController < CountrySelectedDelegate >
   ```
2. create the call `ViewB`

   ```
   ViewB *viewBObjc=[[ViewB alloc] init];
   [viewBObjc setMyDelegate:self];
   [[self navigationController] presentViewController:ViewB animated:YES completion:Nil];
   ```
3. implement the delegate on `ViewA`

   ```
   -(void)selectedCountry: (NSInteger)countryReturned
   {
       NSLog(@"Country Id is :%d", countryReturned);
   }
   ```

Comment: Using self.myDelegate = self in viewControllerB give a warning - assigning a strong incompatible type viewcControllerB *const_strong'

Comment: set the delegate to that view controller where you want to get back your value.

Comment: Thanks. But the delegate is now nil.

Comment: Ok, let me clear first. You are on ViewA and you called ViewB from where you want to pull back data. Am I right?

Comment: Correct - viewA calls viewB. didSelectRowAtIndexPath in viewB dismisses the view - and calls delegate.

Comment: I have updated my answer check once. Are you doing the same and it's not working?? Because I just did that and it's work as it should be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46196/discussion-between-tander-and-tapas-pal)

Comment: This works. If I don't use UinavigationController. If I do, I get a crash. Is there a way to load the view in a navigationcontroller using the same code?

Comment: You used storyboard & I had never used storyboard so no idea bro.. :(

Comment: Thanks anyway bud. I'll figure it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Set delegate by

```
//in ViewControllerB
self.myDelegate = [self parentViewController];
```

or

```
- (IBAction)countrySelect:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    ViewControllerB *vc = (ViewControllerB *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CountrySelection"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UINavigationControllerOperationPop;
    vc. myDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```